# chart.js Annotation Plugin - multiline annotations

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2, chartjs-plugin-annotation

I have created a graph using react-chartjs-2 with annotation plugin. The documentation simply states:

```
// Text to display in label - default is null. Provide an array to display values on a new line
        content: "Test label",
```

Does this mean I can have each value in the array in a separate line? When I use it, all the values are printed as one comma-separated line.

my code:

```
label: {
        //...
        content: ['aaa','bbb','ccc'],
        //...
}
```